# Highcharts yaxis higher values displayed lower

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am looking for a javascript solution to display *rankings* across time.

Being familiar with [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) I am wondering if there is a way to display rankings in a "user-friendly way", by which I mean: with the **#1 ranking being at the top of the chart**, and the **last ranking being at the bottom**.

Does anyone know if this is possible? or of an alternative solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can reverse the Y axis to achieve this (see [ref](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#yAxis--reversed))

```
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Rank'
    },
    allowDecimals: false,
    reversed: true,
    min: 0.5,
    startOnTick: false,
    endOnTick: false,
    max: 3.5
}
```

I made a small example resulting in:
[image]

Source here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MybCM/)