# Google Charts yaxis higher values displayed lower

Tags: google-visualization

I am looking for a way to display rankings across time, using Google Charts.

(this is the same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226105/highcharts-yaxis-higher-values-displayed-lower), but this time using Google Charts instead of Highcharts)

Is there a way to display rankings in a "user-friendly way", by which I mean: with the #1 ranking being at the top of the chart, and the last ranking being at the bottom.

I wish to use the [line charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart.html).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ok, I found the option:

vAxis: {direction: -1} will reverse the y Axis

hAxis: {direction: -1} will reverse the x Axis

```
chart.draw(data, {vAxis: {direction: -1}, width: 400, height: 240, title: 'Rank'});
```